# How to correctly install and run ESET Remote Administrator?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-access, remote, eset

As the title says, I need help with this problem, in my work we are about to implement this system, so I was researching on how to make it work... But it wasn't easy at all... 
I did the following:

[EDIT]

1. Install it on a Windows 10 Pro x64 using the all in one installer, but it didn't work, when it finished the install process it asks for the web console and it uses the localhost, it didn't work, the page cannot load
2. Install it on a Windows Server 2012 x64 using the all in one installer and it is the same result as above
3. Using the OVA virtual machine privided by ESET and the result is the same, it asks for localhost and the page cannot load

I did follow the manual, and even the tutorials on youtube...

And nothing seems to work, I can't open the localhost

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer? Have you run the application? With a specific paid-for application such as ESET RA and a big problem such as this you should probably start by calling ESET support or searching through their KB. Also, you haven't really given us much of any information in this question so far. Please be more clear how you installed the package and what expected or unexpected behavior occurred.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I'll edit my question adding my experience

Comment: I'd suggest to ask directly on official [ESET Remote Administrator](https://forum.eset.com/forum/38-eset-remote-administrator/) forum.